# Where can I download Visual C++ 2015 Build Tools?

Tags: visual-studio

A program I am installing requires Visual C++ 2015 Build Tools. However, I am unable to find these anywhere. The link they provided 404s. So I tried googling it. The top result: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/03/31/announcing-the-official-release-of-the-visual-c-build-tools-2015/
actually downloads the 2017 version.

And the second result is just Microsoft Build Tools 2015, and I have no idea whether that's the same thing: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48159

So where can I find the download for Visual C++ 2015 Build Tools?

Comment: At the moment, one appears to be able to download it here: https://download.microsoft.com/download/5/f/7/5f7acaeb-8363-451f-9425-68a90f98b238/visualcppbuildtools_full.exe

Answer (score 7):

> So where can I find the download for Visual C++ 2015 Build Tools?

You can download it from the Visual Studio website.

[image]

When I launched the installation I was able to confirm that the `Microsoft Build Tools 2015` is indeed `Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools`.

[image]

In order to get the download to display, on the page you reference, click on the `Older Versions` button.

[image]

Source: [Still want an older version?](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/older-downloads/)

> The 2015 build tools were incorporated into the Visual Studio 2017 Build Tools.

This, of course, is indeed false.  `Build Tools for Visual Studio 2017` installs supports an entirely different build chain.  `Build Tools for Visual Studio 2017` as it's predecessor can replace a Visual Studio installation to build software.

Comment: The links require you to log into your Microsoft account on the website, join the developer program, which is of course free.  I cannot provide a direct link to the download, nor is it required, since Microsoft still distributes it.